# Efeito com JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Boa noite a todos. Estou escrevendo um *script* no qual ele tem a função de multiplicar o valor digitado nos `inputs` e me dar o resultado que eu queira saber.

Como faço para quando eu digitar, por exemplo: **100,00**, ele me dar o valor e chamar uma imagem abaixo do `input` "resultado".

Vou configurar a imagem 50x50 que vai ficar oculta, tipo:

```
<img src="teste.jpg" style="display:none">
```

Aí irei pôr o valor de 90 a 100, e quando eu digitar entre esses valores 
irá chamar essa imagem "teste.jpg" abaixo do `input`.

Eu já tentei com `if{}else{}`. Se alguém poder me ajudar ficarei muito grato.

Este é o código:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        #demo3 { display: none;}
        #resultado {margin-left: 500px;}
    </style>
</head>
   <body>
   <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.maskMoney.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script> 
function soma() 
{
    var valor;
    var campo = form.campo1.value;
    if(campo >=1  && campo < 99){
        valor=23;
    }else{
        valor=25;
    }
    form.campo4.value = parseInt(campo) * parseInt(valor) 
}

  function limitarInput(obj) {
    obj.value = obj.value.substring(0,8);
  }
</script>
<form name="form">
<input name="campo1" id="demo4"><br> 
<input name="campo2" value="" id="demo3"><br>  
<input name="campo4" readonly id="resultado"><br>
<input type="button" onclick="soma()" value="CALCULAR">
</form>
<img src="teste.jpg" style="display:none">
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se entendi bem a sua pergunta, basta mudar o `display` da imagem quando os valores atenderem ao critério sugerido, usando `if`.

**Nota:** é importante atribuir um `id` à imagem para facilitar a manipulação da mesma:

```
<img id="imagem" src="teste.jpg" style="display:none">
```

Sendo assim, basta acrescentar o `if` à sua função `soma()`:

```
if(campo >= 90 && campo <= 100){
    // torno o valor display da imagem vazio, assim ela será exibida
    document.getElementById("imagem").style.display = "";
}
```

```js
function soma() 
{
    var valor;
    var campo = form.campo1.value;
    if(campo >=1  && campo < 99){
        valor=23;
    }else{
        valor=25;
    }
 
if(campo >= 90 && campo <= 100){
 document.getElementById("imagem").style.display = "";
}
    form.campo4.value = parseInt(campo) * parseInt(valor) 
}

  function limitarInput(obj) {
    obj.value = obj.value.substring(0,8);
  }
```

```html
<form name="form">
<input name="campo1" id="demo4"><br> 
<input name="campo2" value="" id="demo3"><br>  
<input name="campo4" readonly id="resultado"><br>
<input type="button" onclick="soma()" value="CALCULAR">
</form>
<img id="imagem" src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/76060-200.png" style="display:none">
```

Comment: Obrigado eu vou testar aqui no projeto que eu estou fazendo, caso eu queria por mais do que uma imagem é só eu atribuir outro IF ? com o valor que eu desejar ?

Comment: Se o valor que vc deseja verificar no `if` for outro, pode por sim.

Comment: Obrigado Dvdsamm ! testei aqui deu  super certo você é de mais :)